# Parsing a string, using action script

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on a flex site,

I want to parse the string below:
http://virtual.s1.c7beta.com/rpc/raw?c=Pictures&m=download_picture&key=a4fb33241662c35fe0b46c7e40a5b416&session_id=2b7075f175f599b9390dd06f7b724ee7

and remove the &session_id=2b7075f175f599b9390dd06f7b724ee7 from it.

How should i do it.

also later on when i get the url from database without session_id, i will attach the new session_id to it. Please tell me how to do that too.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the short version but you can use URLVariable to get all the field(name, value) into an object and then add or delete any field you want.

Separate url and query:

```
var url : String = "http://virtual.s1.c7beta.com/rpc/raw?c=Pictures&m=download%5Fpicture&key=a4fb33241662c35fe0b46c7e40a5b416&session%5Fid=2b7075f175f599b9390dd06f7b724ee7";
var idxQMark : int = url.indexOf("?");
var qry : String = "";
```

Build url variable from query

```
var uv : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
if (idxQMark > 0) {
 qry = url.substr(idxQMark + 1);
 url = url.substr(0, idxQMark);
 uv.decode(qry);
}
```

NOw you can access whatever field you need or delete them

```
delete uv.session_id;
```

Rebuild the query when needed

```
qry = uv.toString();
```

// get back you new URL

```
if (qry != "") {
 url = url + "?" + qry;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For URI parsing check out the URI class provided in as3corelib.
http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/net/URI.as

For your specific case, you can clear the parts of the URI you don't want.

```
var url : String = "http://virtual.s1.c7beta.com/rpc/raw?c=Pictures&m=download%5Fpicture&key=a4fb33241662c35fe0b46c7e40a5b416&session%5Fid=2b7075f175f599b9390dd06f7b724ee7";
var uri : URI = new URI(url);
uri.query = "";
uri.fragment = "";
var shortenedUrl : String = uri.toString();
```

Or if you know you want to construct your url from just the scheme, authority, and path (i.e., you don't need to preserve port, username, password, etc.) you can build the url from parts.

```
var shortenedUrl : String = uri.scheme + "://" + uri.authority + "/" + uri.path;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure that sessionid will be last you could split on the & using the as3 string.split functionhttp://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#split%28%29

then rebuild the string using a for loop leaving out strings that start with session_id using the string.indexOf function http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#indexOf%28%29 to see if "session_id" is at index 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in Flex ... here's an [example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_01.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the session ID will always be the last variable in the query string:

```
var newStr:String = myStr.slice(0, myStr.indexOf("&session"));
```